nginx minimal auth_request for personal home server (raspberry-pi), please review
All I want is a wide, simple and fool-proof way to protect all my locations (mainly self hosted stuff) in nginx
Some notes:

Before I was using basic_auth but I was getting the login dialog popping up every time. I wanted to skip that step so I tried using auth_request.
having the password stored in the conf file is fine-ish for my use case, but I am open to simple suggestions

using a php to answer the auth request is not a good solution as this script would be executed for every request and this is an overkill for the raspberrypi



Please let me know what you think:
site configuration file:
    server
    {
       listen 443 ssl http2;

       [..usual certs/roots/etc..]

       auth_request /auth-request.html;

       location = /auth-request.html {
           internal;
           auth_request off;

           # password in plain text, should be 
           # ok-ish for my personal use case
           if ($cookie_skip_http_auth = "password123") {
               return 200;
           }
           return 401;
       }

       error_page 401 /login.html;

       # this page just ask for a password and stores 
       # it in a cookie called "skip_http_auth" 
       #
       location = /auth/login.html {  
           auth_request off;
       }

       ##########################################

       location  / {

       }

    }

login.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  let expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function ask_for_password(auth_cookie)
{
     var value = prompt("Please enter the password:","");
     if (value != "" && value != null) {
       setCookie(auth_cookie, value, 10000);
     }
}
</script>
</head>
    <body onload="ask_for_password('skip_http_auth')"></body>
</html>

nginx.conf (to prevent cookie stealing)
http {
   [...]
   add_header Set-Cookie "Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure";
   
}

